# Como informar o valor do Table Header (th) para um data-title

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma tabela responsiva com tabulação vertical, 
porém preciso criar um `data-title=""` com o mesmo valor do campo(th).

Consegui criar o data-title usando o seguinte js:

```
<script>
  $('th').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).data(''));
  });
</script>
```

a minha tabela está assim já com o data-title :

```
<th id="C003" data-title="[object Object]">
<div id="apexir_C003" onclick="gReport.controls.widget(this.id)">Código</div></th>
```

Eu gostaria de passar para o *data-title* o valor da div, nesse exemplo: "Código", seria possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então você quer passar o innerText do elemento para data-title, não o atributo data.

```
$('th').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).text());
});
```

Ou sem jQuery:

```
for (let el of document.getElementsByTagName('th')) {
  el.dataset.title = el.innerText.trim();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, 
dessa forma ele passou toda a linha do th para o data-title.

Ficou assim: `data-title="<div id="apexir_C003" onclick="gReport.controls.widget(this.id)" style="text-align:center;">Código</div>"`

Comment: Esqueci que sua `th` tinha elementos internos, já editei a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado pela força.

Comment: Se a resposta lhe serviu, aceite-a como resposta para que a mesma fique como aceita pelo site.